# Visual Basic - Writing / Overwriting into a text line adds a new line

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hello everyone I made a simple program that takes my external IP and places in a my websites public camera. And I got a problem - The program is making a txt file with the ip inside it and uploads it to the server.When the program is overwriting/editing/creating the file its adding an empty new line which messes up my PHP code...
This is the code used for both overwriting/editing and creating the file

```
Dim strFile As String = "c:/IPtoUse.txt"
    Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(strFile)
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(strFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        sw.WriteLine( _
            IIf(fileExists, GetIP, GetIP))
    End Using
```

(the GetIP function is getting my ip from my server) 
This ends up with another empty line. How can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that when the stream is opened on top of an existing file, the code writes an extra linefeed at the end, but when it creates a new file, it doesn't, implying that there is some "magic" happening inside StreamWriter related to this? If so, how about just deleting the file first, if it exists?

Comment: Oh... Hmm didn't thought about it... Gonna give it a try. But I will still wait for other answers (I'm new to visual basic and I want to learn all the possible ways to fix a problem) Edit: Looks like I was wrong it still happens also when the file is first created...

Comment: I would assume it did, since you're calling `WriteLine`. Try calling `Write` instead.

Comment: Thanks it works! Can you write it as an answer so I can mark this post as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on the information from the question *and* comments, it seems that your file will end up with an additional linefeed at the end in both cases (ie. both for new and modified files).

The reason for this is that you're using the `WriteLine` method, which will append a newline at the end of the text it writes, even if that text already ends with a newline.

Simply change the code to use the `Write` method instead of the `WriteLine` method and you should end up with a file that contains only the text passed to the method.